# ArrayCollection of data for label test in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, adobe, arraycollection, bindable

My label text is not showing up after binding the arraycollection to the label text. Could I see an example of how to properly bind an arraycollection to a labels text?

Comment: How about you show us your code and then we can help yo determine what is wrong?

Comment: Yes.  Definitely show us some code... because this should just work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I am confused to what your problem is.  When I do it, it prints the `ArrayCollection` just fine:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        var data:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(["1", "2", "3", "4"]);   
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Label text="{data}" />
```

prints out: **1,2,3,4**

What type of data is in your `ArrayCollection`?  Do you need to define `toString()` on your data type?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you shoud try binding to an element of the ArrayCollection? Because binding to the whole ArrayCollection as a text to a label does not make sense.
Some code would be useful.

Comment: I disagree that it doesn't make sense.  When you bind the text value of a `Label` to an `ArrayCollection`, it will call `toString()` on that `ArrayCollection`, which calls `toString()` on the items and comma-separates them.  Therefore, you get "1,2,3,4" when you bind to an `ArrayCollection` with those items in it.